# Simple Turing machine simulator

Tags: c, beginner, error-handling, simulation, state-machine

Yesterday I got a sudden urge to go from writing Python to something, well, more UNIX core-ish. I read some examples on [here](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/) and decided I might as well put some of that stuff to use to test something else I'm working on: computability theory. Ergo: I wanted to write a basic, one tape, Turing machine simulator.

It works, as far as I know. It's not brilliant, and the Turing machine is hard coded in this early version, but it is functional.

I'd really like some review on the code. One thing I'm particularly curious about is whether I'm doing appropriate error checking and handling. e.g. are there specific cases where `assert` is more appropriate or where I should do more error checking?

**turing.h**

```
#ifndef __turing_h__
#define __turing_h__

#define MAX_TRANSITIONS 5
#define MAX_STATES 25

// forward declare structs
struct State;
struct Transition;

typedef enum {
    LEFT, RIGHT
} Direction;

typedef enum {
    FALSE, TRUE
} Bool;

struct Transition {
    char input;
    char write;
    Direction move;
    struct State *next;
};

typedef struct Transition Transition;

struct State {
    int id;
    int trans_count;
    struct Transition* transitions[ MAX_TRANSITIONS ];
    Bool accept;
    Bool reject;
};

typedef struct State State;

struct Turing {
    int state_count;
    State* states[ MAX_STATES ];
    State* current;
    int head;
};

typedef struct Turing Turing;

#endif
```

**turing.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "turing.h"

// disable debug mode
#define NDEBUG
#include "debug.h"

// used to hand out ids
int state_id = 0;

void die( char *message )
{
    if( message )
    {
        printf( "Error: %s.\n", message );
    }

    // exit unsuccesfully
    exit(1);
}

Transition* Transition_create( char input, char write, Direction move, State *next )
{
    // allocate memory
    Transition *trans = malloc( sizeof( Transition ));
    if( ! trans ) die( "Memory error" );

    trans->input = input;
    trans->write = write;
    trans->move = move;
    trans->next = next;

    return trans;
}

void Transition_destroy( Transition* trans )
{
    free( trans );
}

State* State_create( Bool accept, Bool reject )
{
    // allocate mem
    State *state = malloc( sizeof( State ));
    if( ! state ) die( "Memory error" );

    state->id = state_id++;
    state->accept = accept;
    state->reject = reject;
    state->trans_count = 0;

    return state;
}

void State_add_transition( State *state, Transition *trans )
{
    // check if we can still add another transition
    if( state->trans_count == MAX_TRANSITIONS ) {
        char buffer[ 50 ];
        sprintf( buffer, "State %d already has the maximum amount of transitions.", state->id );

        die( buffer );
    }

    // add the transition
    state->transitions[ state->trans_count ] = trans;
    state->trans_count++;
}

void State_destroy( State *state )
{
    int i = 0;

    // loop over its transitions
    for( i = 0; i < state->trans_count; i++ ) {
        Transition *trans = state->transitions[ i ];
        if( !trans ) die( "Could not fetch transition." );

        Transition_destroy( trans );
    }

    free( state );
}

Turing* Turing_create()
{
    // allocate mem
    Turing *machine = malloc( sizeof( Turing ));

    machine->state_count = 0;
    machine->current = NULL;
    machine->head = 0;

    return machine;
}

void Turing_destroy( Turing *machine )
{
    int i = 0;

    // loop over it's states
    for( i = 0; i < machine->state_count; i++ ) {
        State *state = machine->states[ i ];
        if( !state ) die( "Could not fetch turing state" );

        State_destroy( state );
    }

    free( machine );
}

void Turing_add_state( Turing *machine, State *state )
{
    if( machine->state_count == MAX_STATES ) {
        die( "The turing machine already has the maximum amount of states" );
    }

    // add the state
    machine->states[ machine->state_count++ ] = state;
}

State* Turing_step( Turing *machine, char* tape, int tape_len )
{
    int i = 0;
    char input = tape[ machine->head ];
    State* state = machine->current;

    // look for a transition on the given input
    for( i = 0; i < state->trans_count; i++ ) {
        Transition* trans = state->transitions[ i ];
        if( !trans ) die( "Transition retrieval error" );

        // check if this is a transition in the given char input
        if( trans->input == input ) {
            debug( "Found transition for input %c", input );

            State *next = trans->next;
            if( !next ) die( "Transitions to NULL state" );

            // write if nescesary
            if( trans->write != '\0' ) {
                debug( "Writing %c", trans->write );
                tape[ machine->head ] = trans->write;
                debug( "Writing done" );
            }

            // move the head
            if( trans->move == LEFT ) {
                if( machine->head > 0 ) {
                    machine->head--;
                    debug( "Moved head left" );
                }
            } else {
                if( machine->head + 1 >= tape_len ) {
                    die( "Machine walked of tape on right side" );
                }

                machine->head++;
                debug( "Moved head right" );
            }

            // move the machine to the next state
            debug( "Setting current state" );
            machine->current = next;

            return next;
        }
    }

    char buffer[ 50 ];
    sprintf( buffer, "Turing machine blocked: state %d for input %c", state->id, input );

    die( buffer );
}

void Turing_run( Turing *machine, char *tape, int tapelen )
{
    // check if the start state is configured properly
    if( !machine->current ) die( "Turing machine has now start state" );

    while( TRUE ) {
        State* state = Turing_step( machine, tape, tapelen );

        if( state->accept ) {
            printf( "Input accepted in state: %d\n", state->id );
            break;
        } else if( state->reject ) {
            printf( "Input rejected in state: %d\n", state->id );
            break;
        } else {
            printf( "Moved to state: %d\n", state->id );    
        }
    }
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    Turing* machine = Turing_create();

    State* q1 = State_create( FALSE, FALSE );
    State* q2 = State_create( FALSE, FALSE );
    State* q3 = State_create( FALSE, FALSE );
    State* q4 = State_create( FALSE, FALSE );
    State* q5 = State_create( FALSE, FALSE );
    State* qaccept = State_create( TRUE, FALSE );
    State* qreject = State_create( FALSE, TRUE );

    Transition* q1_r_space = Transition_create( ' ', '\0', RIGHT, qreject );
    Transition* q1_r_x = Transition_create( 'x', '\0', RIGHT, qreject );
    Transition* q1_q2_zero = Transition_create( '0', ' ', RIGHT, q2 );
    Transition* q2_q2_x = Transition_create( 'x', '\0', RIGHT, q2 );
    Transition* q2_a_space = Transition_create( ' ', '\0', RIGHT, qaccept );
    Transition* q2_q3_zero = Transition_create( '0', 'x', RIGHT, q3 );
    Transition* q3_q3_x = Transition_create( 'x', '\0', RIGHT, q3 );
    Transition* q3_q4_zero = Transition_create( '0', '\0', RIGHT, q4 );
    Transition* q3_q5_space = Transition_create( ' ', '\0', LEFT, q5 );
    Transition* q4_q3_zero = Transition_create( '0', 'x', RIGHT, q3 );
    Transition* q4_q4_x = Transition_create( 'x', '\0', RIGHT, q4 );
    Transition* q4_r_space = Transition_create( ' ', '\0', RIGHT, qreject );
    Transition* q5_q5_zero = Transition_create( '0', '\0', LEFT, q5 ); 
    Transition* q5_q5_x = Transition_create( 'x', '\0', LEFT, q5 ); 
    Transition* q5_q2_space = Transition_create( ' ', '\0', RIGHT, q2 ); 

    State_add_transition( q1, q1_r_space );
    State_add_transition( q1, q1_r_x );
    State_add_transition( q1, q1_q2_zero );
    State_add_transition( q2, q2_q2_x );
    State_add_transition( q2, q2_a_space );
    State_add_transition( q2, q2_q3_zero );
    State_add_transition( q3, q3_q3_x );
    State_add_transition( q3, q3_q4_zero );
    State_add_transition( q3, q3_q5_space );
    State_add_transition( q4, q4_q3_zero );
    State_add_transition( q4, q4_q4_x );
    State_add_transition( q4, q4_r_space );
    State_add_transition( q5, q5_q5_zero );
    State_add_transition( q5, q5_q5_x );
    State_add_transition( q5, q5_q2_space );

    Turing_add_state( machine, q1 );
    Turing_add_state( machine, q2 );
    Turing_add_state( machine, q3 );
    Turing_add_state( machine, q4 );
    Turing_add_state( machine, q5 );
    Turing_add_state( machine, qaccept );
    Turing_add_state( machine, qreject );

    machine->current = q1;

    char* input = "0000000000000000  ";
    int len = strlen( input );
    char* tape = malloc( len * sizeof( char ));
    strcpy( tape, input );
    Turing_run( machine, tape, len );

    // clean up
    Turing_destroy( machine );
    free( tape );
}
```

**debug.h**

```
#ifndef __debug_h__
#define __debug_h__

#ifndef NDEBUG
#define debug(M, ... ) fprintf( stderr, "DEBUG: %s:%d: " M "\n", __FILE__,   __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__ )
#else
#define debug(M, ... )
#endif

#endif
```

For now the simulator is configured to accept on input strings from the language:

> ```
> L = { 0^2^n | n > 0 }
> ```

Or: all strings of 0s whose length is a power of 2.

If you happen to have Sipser *Introduction to the Theory of Computation*. It's on page 145 of the 2<sup>nd</sup> edition.

---

[GIT repo up](https://github.com/ElessarWebb/turing.git) and documentation on the way (we have a [tiny wiki](https://github.com/ElessarWebb/turing/wiki) with basic usage)

Comment: You might find this page interesting: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8787/turing-machine-simulator/8795#2381

Comment: If you would like a review on the revised code, please [ask another question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1763/9357).

Answer (score 12):

AJ, I like it.  Very nicely coded.

Here are some comments. I've omitted things already mentioned by @LokiAstari

- forward declaration of `struct Transition` is unnecessary.
- `die`, prefer to print errors to `stderr`
- `exit(1)` prefer `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`
- some noisey comments ("exit unsucessfully", "allocate memory" etc)
- `State_create` does not initialise `transitions` (probably benign)
- `sprintf` is often used badly, resulting in buffer overflows. `snprintf` is
  preferred.  But as you use it only before dying, no risk.
- `Turing_create` does not check `malloc` (other uses do).
- do you prefer `type* var` or `type *var`?  I prefer the latter, but
  whichever you use, consistency is best.
- don't you get a warning (control may reach end of non-void function, or
  similar) from `Turing_step`?
- in some places you can define loop variables in the loop: `for( int i = 0; ...`
- make local functions static.  This is good practice but for a small project
  like this makes no difference.
- your list of Transition_create calls in `main` would be more readable if aligned.
- your `main` has some issues in the copying of `input`.

  - `strlen` returns `size_t` and `malloc` takes `size_t`. So best to use
    `size_t` (-Wsign-conversion)
  - sizeof(char) is 1 by definition
  - you malloced one too few bytes for the string copy.
  - you could have used `strdup` if you have it.
  - but note that mallocing a copy of `input` is not necessary.  You can just declare the string as `char input[] = "..."` instead of `char* input = "..."` and it will be writable.
  - if you use `char input[]` you need not do `strlen(input)` - just `sizeof input -1`
- passing the length of the input string around seems unnecessary (users of
  the string can check for the terminating '\0')

On error checking and use of `assert`, I think you have done a good job of
checking.  I'm not a big user of asserts (so maybe my thoughts on them are not
of much use to you).  I'm always uneasy using an assert - they are funny
things. They say, in effect, that the tested condition is so important that it
is worth exiting if it occurs during testing, **but** that if it occurs during
normal use (NDEBUG) it can be ignored.  That is illogical unless you can be
sure that all possible assert failures can be detected during testing.  To me
that implies that asserts should be used only to test for errors that are
intrinsic to the program and have no dependence upon the data or the runtime.
For example checking whether `malloc` failed would use an `if` condition
whereas checking for something that can only happen if an algorithm is wrongly
coded is a fair use of `assert`.  In your case, I might be tempted to use
`assert` where you check array entries are not NULL:

```
    Transition *trans = state->transitions[ i ];
    assert( trans );
```

But I've seen asserts sprinkled around like confettii, so opinions clearly
differ.   Maybe other reviewers will be able to help.

Comment: Thank you. Some of these I already incorporated. Some of them I'll research a bit. I agree with you on the assert/if dilemma. I see alot of code (in other languages) that seem to forget that asserts are usually not for runtime checking.

Comment: About passing around the string length: I'm getting the impressions there are several opinions on the matter. You either have to make SURE all strings are \0 terminated and rely on C string tools and/or build in extra checks to prevent overflows. You clearly vote for the former. Anyone else?

Comment: AJ, strings should always be terminated with \0 but arrays in general are not. But strings are arrays - maybe that is where the confusion arrises...  Note that I corrected a piece of badly wrong advice above (using sizeof on a pointer!)

Comment: No, there is no confusion. I'm just deliberating whether I should TRUST the strings in my program to be properly terminated. Should I?

Comment: Yes, if it is created by the compiler (from your quoted string, as in "01234..") it will definitely be terminated. If created by someone using strcpy (as in your original code) then it depends upon the code.  But if the \0 is missing, using strlen to find out how long it is will also fail, as strlen won't find the \0 it needs.  So in practice you have to assume it is correctly terminated.

Answer (score 7):

Identifiers with two underscores are reserved for the implementation (so don't use them).
Also MACROS (things defined by #define) are traditionally all uppercase (because they do not obey scope rules (because they are not part of the C language but part of the pre-processor system) we make them all uppercase to make sure that we don't accidentally clash with other identifiers).

```
#ifndef __turing_h__
#define __turing_h__
```

If you are going to forward declare these then also do the appropriate typedefs.

```
struct State;
struct Transition;    

// Add
typedef struct State State;
typedef struct Transition Transition;
```

Now you will be able to refer to then without using the prefix struct.

Don't use all caps. A macro (with no scope boundary may play havake with these identifiers).

```
typedef enum {
    LEFT, RIGHT
} Direction;
```

The system header files aready define FALSE/TRUE. Also in this situation you define TRUE as 1. This is not correct. The only thing you can say about `TRUE` is `(!FALSE)`. Which is not necessarily the same as 1.

```
typedef enum {
    FALSE, TRUE
} Bool;
```

Nothing wrong with this.
But if you lay out your type with the chars first then you may not get the best packing arrangement. Always order them from largest to smallest (if you care about layout (usually it is not a big thing but if you have large space requirements and can become an issue)).

```
struct Transition {
    char input;
    char write;
    Direction move;
    State *next;
};
```

So I would have layed it out like this:

```
typedef struct Transition {
    State     *next;      // At least as big as an int (but can be bigger).
    Direction  move;      // Enum is an int.
    char       input;     // Now chars.
    char       write;
} Transition;
```

Comment: "Don't use all caps." Actually, all caps is a very common way to declare constants, enums and all manner of global identifiers, not just macros.

Comment: "...you define TRUE as 1. This is not correct."  Yes it is perfectly correct. Always make the code compatible with the C standard bool type, which is explicitly guaranteed to be 1 and not some magical "not 0 maybe 1". The best is of course to use the standard bool type from stdbool.h.

Comment: Ah `stdbool.h`. Another useful note!

Answer (score 5):

I just have one small note in addition to the other answers.

Your `#include`s should be organized differently:

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <stdlib.h>
> #include <assert.h>
> #include <string.h>
> #include "turing.h"
> ```

It's best to include your own headers first, in order to avoid any possible dependency issues with the system libraries.  In other words, you shouldn't force your headers to be exposed to other libraries, especially if that is not intended to happen.

In addition, you can sort your headers in a certain order, such as alphabetically.  This will make it easier to keep track of them.

```
#include "turing.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Answer (score -1):

as the malloc() return `void *` 
you must correct all the memory allocation statements

`Turing *machine = malloc( sizeof( Turing ));`

---> `Turing *machine = (Turing*) malloc( sizeof( Turing ));`

and so on

Comment: No, don't do that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc